# How to set up Sublime 2 or 3 to place its panel on the right side of its window?

Tags: sublimetext

I prefer to have all the side panels on the right. Is this possible with Sublime 2?

Comment: Ivan, it doesn't look like you can do this. Bummer, I agree.

Comment: I looked into the .sublime-theme file and couldn't find any clear way to do it either.

Answer (score 1):

It's not implemented yet, but you can upvote it here : http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/54835-side-bar-on-the-right-side/